# Remove everything after last folder htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+) index.php?task=location&state=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

It's for URL's like:

```
website.com/texas/houston
website.com/new-york/new-york
...
```

If I go to the URL website.com/texas/houston/bfdsjfds, I get the same content as for the URL website.com/texas/houston.
How can I remove the "/bfdsjfds" in above example? Or redirect that page to a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use end anchor `$` to only match `/state/city`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?task=location&state=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

This will automatically return 404 for `website.com/texas/houston/bfdsjfds` type of URLs.

Comment: Already tried that but does not work in this code. I'm already using it (with success) for other rewrite rules like: RewriteRule ^contact?$ index.php?task=contact [L]. But in the code from my question it does not work.

Comment: Can you clarify your comment a bit more? For which URL it doesn't work? What problem do you get when it doesn't work? Do you have more rules if yes then post them in question.

Comment: I just realized how dumb I was :) Your solution does work! I had other rewrite rules below the one shown in my opening question. I had to add "?$" to all of them to make it work. It's quite obvious ofcourse. Thanks a lot!